# Нахождение текста на изображении

Tags: распознавание, алгоритм

Есть страница манги, на которой в произвольных местах может быть расположен текст. Нужно найти все области с текстом на картинке.

Большая часть его находится в белых облачках, понятное дело, но, однако, не весь.
Какие есть алгоритмы нахождения текста на картинках? Как это делают программы типа ABBYY? Есть какие-то критерии?

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри в сторону библиотеки OpenCV, если не лень разбираться. С помощью неё можно произвести обучение на какой нибудь объект (в твоем случае буквы/текст). В итоге получишь xml файлик, который можно использовать. Если интересно:

- http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ - библиотека
- http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html - обучение
- http://robocraft.ru/page/opencv/ - материал на русском языке

Обучение проходит достаточно долго, до нескольких дней в зависимости от выборки. Зато распознает в итоге - глазом не успеешь моргнуть))

Comment: Надо поглядеть доки, что она умеет *отправился в интернет*

Comment: =) еще про границы Канни почитайте. Не уверен что лучше здесь использовать - Хаара или контурный анализ.